# RSS Feed Button not showing

Tags: widgets, rss

I am trying to add follow feature of RSS feed so that other people can follow my RSS feed to get updated.

I am trying this with adding widget and in that widget I choose the RSS feed.

[image]

and I am using my feedurl in that - like this - https://christmasgiftsjustforgirls.com/feed/

[image]

**But after adding this I see that list of links are coming instead of one single button to follow rss feed.**

[image]

my goal is to achieve button like this:

[image]

Please help on this, how can I get button like this, any plugin that I can use or any suggestions? BTW I am using Astra free theme